# Почему flex не сжимается при изменении окна?

Tags: html, css

В общем написал блок на flex. По сути расстояние между картами должно сжиматься из-за уменьшения окна (отзывчивая верстка), но этого не происходит. Причем это происходит у двух блоков, уже несколько часов не могу понять почему. Из важного указал

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

```css
p,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.price-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.price-card {
  width: 360px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-card--active {}

.price-card__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.price-card__price {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Raleway";
}

.price-card__price--lg {
  font-size: 110px;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
}

.prace-card__time {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff8b38;
}

.prace-card__line-orange--active {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff8b38;
}

.prace-card__description {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #8e8e92;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block7">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="top-text block7__top-text">
      <h1 class="top-text__header">PRICING OPTIONS</h1>
      <div class="in_line top-text__in_line"></div>
      <p class="top-text__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="price-list">
      <div class="price-card">
        <h3 class="price-card__header">Basic</h3>
        <p class="price-card__price">$ <span class="price-card__price--lg">0</span></p>
        <p class=" prace-card__time">Free for Life</p>
        <div class="prace-card__line-orange"></div>
        <p class="prace-card__description">1 gb of space</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">10 gb of bandwidth</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">3 websites</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">Basic Customization</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">wordpress integration</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">email support</p>
      </div>
      <div class="price-card price-list__card price-card--active">
        <h3 class="price-card__header">Professional</h3>
        <p class="price-card__price">$ <span class="price-card__price--lg">19</span></p>
        <p class=" prace-card__time">Monthly Payment</p>
        <div class="prace-card__line-orange--active">
          <p class="prace-card__most-popular">OUR MOST POPULAR</p>
        </div>
        <p class="prace-card__description">5 gb of space</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">50 gb of bandwidth</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">12 websites</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">Advanced Customization</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">wordpress integration</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">email support</p>
      </div>
      <div class="price-card price-list__card">
        <h3 class="price-card__header">Enterprise</h3>
        <p class="price-card__price">$ <span class="price-card__price--lg">70</span></p>
        <p class=" prace-card__time">Monthly Payment</p>
        <div class="prace-card__line-orange"></div>
        <p class="prace-card__description">Unlimited space</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">unlimited bandwidth</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">100 websites</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">Advanced Customization</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">wordpress integration</p>
        <p class="prace-card__description">24/7 customer support</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикол в том, что отдельно данный код корректно работает. Непонятно, что на него может повлиять

Comment: Очевидно же что в этой строке `<div class="prace-card__line-orange--active">
          <p class="prace-card__most-popular">OUR MOST POPULAR</p>
        </div>`  и в классе --active